# Ada: Adding an exception in a separate procedure when reading a file

Tags: file, exception, ada

This is a follow-up of this question:    [Ada: reading from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792230/ada-reading-from-a-file) .

I would like to add an `exception` that checks if the file that I'm opening actually exists or not. I have made a `separate` procedure to avoid code clutter.

Here is the main code `test_read.adb`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;


procedure Test_Read is

   Input_File    : File_Type;
   Value         : Long_Float;

procedure Open_Data (File : in  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Name : in String) is separate;

begin

   Ada.Text_IO.Open (File => Input_File, Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File, Name => "fx.txt");

   while not End_Of_File (Input_File) loop
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => Value);
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.Close (File => Input_File);

end Test_Read;
```

And here is the `separate` body `test_read-open_data.adb` of the procedure `Open_Data`:

```
separate(test_read)
procedure Open_Data (File : in  out Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; 
                     Name : in String) is

   --this procedure prepares a file for reading
   begin
      begin
       Ada.Text_IO.Open
         (File => File,
          Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File,
          Name => Name);
       exception
       when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error =>
          Ada.Text_IO.Put(File => Standard_Error, Item => "File not found.");
      end;
end Open_Data;
```

On compilation I get an error message in the `separate` body `test_read-open_data.adb`:

```
actual for "File" must be a variable
```

How to fix this?

Thanks a lot...

**Update**:

I have now made the following corrections.

1. In `test_read.adb`, I now have `procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Name : in String) is separate;`
2. Updated the *definition* of the same `Open_Data` procedure in `test_read-open_data.adb`.

The program compiles well though I do not see it catch the exception say if I renamed the file `fx.txt` to `fy.txt`. The error message I get is just

```
raised ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR : fx.txt: No such file or directory
```

So I do not get my own error message :*File not found*.

What is still wrong?

Comment: you open the file using `Ada.Text_IO.Open`, and not your own `Open_Data` procedure.

Comment: @ oenone Yes you are right. I totally missed that. This was the cause of the problem. 1 vote up.

Comment: For your update, you are simply trying to catch the wrong exception. Instead of catching `Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error` you should catch `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`. It is useful to read the error messages produced by your program. In this case it is clear that the exception which was raised is `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`.

Comment: @ Schedler I get an  `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR` with either using `when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error =>` or using `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error =>`. So I am not getting an `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`. **And this is wrong** . So how to fix that? 1 vote up!

Comment: @Schedler If you look at the end of http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html you will see that `Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error` is a renaming of `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`. So either name will do.

Comment: I have made a new post [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804239/ada-throwing-wronge-exception-when-opening-a-non-existent-file as this one is getting too long.

Comment: @SimonWright Thanks for the info - I was not aware of this. Thinking of it, it makes sense yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `File` parameter of Open_Data needs to be an `in out` parameter (as in, for example, `Ada.Text_IO.Create`), because you want the opened file to be accessible within `Test_Read`.

You are getting `actual for "File" must be a variable` because an `in` parameter is read-only.

```
procedure Open_Data (File : in out Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; 
                     Name : in     String) is
```

(Personally I rarely type the `in` mode, because it’s the default).

But in any case, it looks as though the reason for the observed behaviour is that `Test_Read`  doesn’t actually call `Open_Data`!

(edited to make the recommended mode `in out` & to suggest calling `Open_Data`)

Comment: @ Simon Wright Thanks. I have made the necessary changes but my exception is not caught as I intend. Please see the **updated** part of the post. 1 vote up.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I guess this has something to do with `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error` vs `Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error`. In order to debug, you can add `when others => ...` to check for unexpected exceptions.

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann `when others => ... ` doesn't make any difference. I still get the same error message as in my post. 1 vote up.

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann Putting `when Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error =>` instead also give the same error message.

Comment: Using `Open_Data (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt"); ` instead of the incorrect `Ada.Text_IO.Open (File => Input_File, Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File, Name => "fx.txt");` solves the issue. I get the message: **File not found....**

*Execution terminated by unhandled exception
Exception name: ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR
Message: file not open*

Comment: `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR` is not what to be expected.

Comment: The caller can’t tell whether the call to `Open_Data` worked or not, so it carries on and tries to read from `Input_File` - which is not open - hence the `Status_Error`. You could call `Text_IO.Is_Open` (personally I wouldn’t have tried to handle the exception in the subprogram, but it’s your design).

Comment: @ Simon Wright Ok. but how the would you go about to handle the exception. Yes it is my design and if it is flawed, please show me the *right* way to do things. 1 vote up.

Comment: There’s good general guidance in AQ&S, http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_5/5-8.html. In your case, the caller of `Open_Data` clearly expects `Text_IO` to be used, so it seems reasonable for it to propagate `Name_Error` rather than trying to handle it itself or create a different exception. It’s then up to the caller (`Test_Read`) to decide what to do; in this case, I’d have put your exception handler at the end of `Test_Read` and just let it terminate. If you really want to output a message in `Open_Data`, consider adding a `raise` statement after doing so?

Comment: @ Simon Wright Thanks for the link and for the explanation. If I have multiple files to open (as I really actually do), then is it still OK to place the exceptions in the main file `test_read.adb`? 1 vote up.

Comment: There’s really no difference at that level between raising an exception and returning a Boolean `Status`. You still need to decide what to do if you can’t open the 7th of 8 files; can you supply suitable defaults, or do you have to bail out anyway? You’d probably use a `begin` try-to-open `exception` do-something `end` structure for each file, where do-something might involve a `return` (which exits the current procedure).

Answer (score 1):

if your goal is to simply check if the file exists, consider using Ada.Directories.Exists

Comment: @ Jarrod I am doing it the above way as then I can add other exceptions as required say `Use_Error` and `Status_Error`. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC: Standard_Error is not a file, but a Stream.

Comment: it does look like one: `function Standard_Error  return File_Type;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason you are not seeing your error message is that you are using Put rather than Put_Line.  Different implementations/platforms treat output to the user's display differently.  To be extra sure you will see the message, follow the Put_Line with a Get_Line.  The Get_Line generally forces the output of the Put_Line.