# Ada: throwing wrong exception when opening a non-existent file

Tags: file, exception, ada

This is a follow up of this [post] [Ada: Adding an exception in a separate procedure when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794485/ada-adding-an-exception-in-a-separate-procedure-when-reading-a-file)

When my code below opens a file that doesn't exist, instead of throwing a `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR`, it is throwing a `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR`.

Below are the codes.

Main file: `test_read.adb`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;


procedure Test_Read is

   Input_File    : File_Type;
   value         : Long_Float;

   procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Name : in String) is separate;

begin

   Open_Data (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt");

   while not End_Of_File (Input_File) loop
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => value);
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop;
    Ada.Text_IO.Close (File => Input_File);

end Test_Read;
```

And the `separate` procedure body `test_read-open_data.adb`:

```
separate (test_read)

procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
                 Name : in String) is

   --this procedure prepares a file for reading
   begin
      begin
         Ada.Text_IO.Open
           (File => File,
            Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File,
            Name => Name);
      exception
         when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error =>
         Ada.Text_IO.Put(File => Standard_Error, Item => "****File not found....****");
   end;
end Open_Data;
```

The *error message* that is thrown:

```
****File not found....****

Execution terminated by unhandled exception
Exception name: ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR
Message: file not open
Call stack traceback locations:
0x40bf0f 0x40ead0 0x424b08 0x424e4a 0x4010b4 0x401146 0x7c817075
[2012-03-21 13:45:44] process exited with status 1 (elapsed time: 00.13s)
```

I have tried a few things:

1. Put `with Ada.IO_Exceptions;` in `test_read.adb` and put `when Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error =>` instead of `when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error =>` in `test_read-open_data.adb`. But there is no change.
2. In `test_read-open_data.adb`, I changed the line `Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File` to make it become `Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Out_File` as shown below:

   Ada.Text_IO.Open
                  (File => File,
                   Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Out_File,
                   Name => Name);

But there is no improvement.

So how to get the **right** `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR`?

**A related question:**

What's the difference between `Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error` and `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR`? In my program I want to be informed when the file of name `fx.txt` does not exist. Which one of these two exceptions is appropriate?

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE (Latest Codes)**

Here are my updated codes:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;


procedure Test_Read is

   Input_File    : File_Type;
   value         : Long_Float;
   Success       : Boolean;

procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Name : in String; Success : out Boolean) is separate;

begin

   Open_Data (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt", Success => Success);
   if not Success then
      return;
   end if;

   while not End_Of_File (Input_File) loop
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => value);
      Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.Close (File => Input_File);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Item => "Reading file success: " & Boolean'Image (Success));

end Test_Read;
```

and the `separate` procedure:

```
separate (test_read)

procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
                 Name : in String; Success : out Boolean) is

   --this procedure prepares a file for reading
     begin
      Success := True;
      begin
         Ada.Text_IO.Open
           (File => File,
            Mode => Ada.Text_IO.Out_File,
            Name => Name);
      exception
         when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error  =>
         Success := False;   
         Ada.Text_IO.Put (File => Standard_Error, Item => "****File not found....****");
      end;
end Open_Data;
```

On compiling **with file fx.txt present**, I get:

```
Execution terminated by unhandled exception
Exception name: ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.MODE_ERROR
Message: file not readable
Call stack traceback locations:
0x40bf2b 0x40ead0 0x424b58 0x424f5a 0x4010b4 0x401146 0x7c817075
[2012-03-22 08:39:39] process exited with status 1 (elapsed time: 00.14s)
```

**And the contents of the file `fx.txt` **get erased** and its contents are not displayed on running the program**

On compiling **with file fx.txt renamed to fy.txt**, I get:

```
****File not found....****
[2012-03-22 08:45:31] process terminated successfully (elapsed time: 00.13s)
```

So what went wrong?

Comment: `Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error` is the same as `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`. It is renamed in the `Ada.Text_IO` package.

Comment: BTW, if you want to create the file if it doesn't exist, call `Ada.Text_IO.Create` in your exception block.

Comment: @ oenone Thanks. Ok for the similarity of the two names. Since we are opening and reading values from a file *that should exist* (from my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794485/ada-adding-an-exception-in-a-separate-procedure-when-reading-a-file, I do not want to add any `Ada.Text_IO.Create`. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is just what I would expect: a `Name_Error` is thrown and caught, *File not found* is printed, and the program continues. `Open_Data` does not tell its caller that the file has not been opened, and the subsequent operations on the file trigger a `Status_Error`. You could, for example, add a `Success : out Boolean` to `Open_Data`'s parameters, or raise an exception (one of your own, or simply re-raise `Name_Error`.

E.g.

```
Open_Data (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt", Success => Success);
if not Success then
   return;
end if;

while not End_Of_File (Input_File) loop
```

Comment: As mentioned in the RM in A.13 (7): "The exception Status_Error is propagated by an attempt to operate upon a file that is not open, and by an attempt to open a file that is already open.", see http://rm.ada.cx/05/RM-A-13.html

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann Ok. I can put a `Boolean` parameter as you say in the procedure `Open_Data` as the last parameter. Then what to include in the calling procedure `Open_Data (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt");?` How to insert the `Boolean` there? To what must the `Boolean` be initialised first? 1 vote up.

Comment: You do not need to initialise it since it is an `out` parameter; I've edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann Thanks. However the contents of the file `fx.txt` gets erased when running the program and its values are not displayed. Please see the **updated post**.

Comment: You don’t need to initialize `Test_Read`’s `Success`, but you do need to write to `Open_Data`’s `Success`! Set it to `True` to begin with and `False` if the file doesn’t get opened.

Comment: @ Simon Wright So I have to take away the initialisation `Success    : Boolean;` and to change the procedure to: `procedure Open_Data (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Name : in String; Success : out Boolean := TRUE)` ? I do not need to do anything with `FALSE`, do I ? 1 vote up.

Comment: No, that won’t compile. What I meant was, insert `Success := True;` after the first `begin` of `Open_Data`, which will be the result if nothing untoward happens. Insert `Success := False;` before the `Put` statement in the exception handler, to be the result on failure.

Comment: @ Simon Wright Thanks. I have tried to implement your suggestions and there are still problems. In the **update** section of my post, you will see the new codes and the outputs.

Comment: You're giving `Mode => Out_File` to Open, which means that you want to write the file. Use `In_File` instead.

Comment: @ Ansgar Esztermann Yeah you're right. I've also added `Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Item => "Reading file success: " & Boolean'Image (Success));` in the exception so that I get a `Reading file success: False` message also in case the file doesn't exist. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering to the updated content of your post.

The content of your file is being deleted because you picked a wrong File_Mode.
Judging by the rest of your code your intention was to read from the file but you specified Ada.Text_IO.Out_File as the operation mode which specifies that the file will be used for writing.

Out_File will also discard the current contents of the file. If you intend to write to the file later on specify Inout_File as the mode or Append_File if your intention is only to append new content to the file without reading or removing the existing content.

As for the ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.MODE_ERROR exception being raised. You asked to read from a file handle opened in write only mode (Out_File) - this is a clear error and results in the exception being raised.

In summary. Change the Mode in the call to Ada.Text_IO.Open from Ada.Text_IO.Out_File to Ada.Text_IO.In_File.